# Proving Subspaces using Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

T : Rn → Rm  is a linear transformation where n,m>= 2

Let V be a subspace of Rn
and let W ={T(v ) | v ∈ V}
. Prove completely that W
is a subspace of Rm.

For this question how do I show that the subspace is non empty, holds under scaler addition and multiplication! I have never proved subspaces with transformations before!

I think I know this subspace is non empty when v is the 0 vector so is T(v) right?

b)Assume now that nullity(T) = 0 and that A =
{
a1; a2; . . . ; ap
}
is a basis for V as
in part (a). Prove completely that the set C =
{
T(a1); T(a2); . . . . ; T(ap)
}
is a basis
for W as in part (a)

Overhere Im lost!
since the nullity is 0 we know the matrix representation of the transformation is invertible. but then what

Comment: for part be can I assume that linear transformations maintain linear independance

Answer (score 3):

$W$ is nonempty since $0=T(0)\in W$. Now, suppose $x,y\in W$. Then there are $u,v\in V$ such that $Tu=x$ and $Tv=y$. Use this to show $x+y\in W$. A similar argument can be used to prove $ax\in W$ for all scalars $a$.
For b), use the fact that :$$0=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iT(a_i)=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ia_i\right) \iff \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ia_i=0$$

Comment: for part b) why is the relationship = 0 . This is confusing can you simplify part b for me please im only in first year linear algebra

Comment: @user126885 $\text{Nullity}=0$ means: $Tx=0\iff x=0$.You need to show that: $0=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iT(a_i)\implies \lambda_i=0$ for all $i$. This is the definition of linear independence.

Comment: For B can't I say that linear transformations preserves linear combinations and subspaces, and nullity  = 0 the set of vectors C must span W since the nullity is 0 and then since Transformations preserve combinations then the set of vectors must be independent in the set C hence the set being a basis for W

Comment: ok thank you! that was all that was left to prove the linear independance.

Answer (score 1):

- We have $T(0_{\Bbb R^n})=0_{\Bbb R^m}\in W$ since $T$ is linear so $W\ne\emptyset$.
- Let $y_1,y_2\in W$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ then there's $x_1,x_2\in V$ s.t.
  $$T(x_1)=y_1\qquad T(x_2)=y_2$$
  but since $V$ is a linear subspace then $\alpha x_1+x_2\in V$ and by linearity of $T$ we have
  $$T(\alpha x_1+ x_2)=\alpha T(x_1)+T(x_2)=\alpha y_1+y_2\in W$$
  hence $W$ is invariant by linear combination. Conclude.